# Need to set current.username in author comment section

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I've created `Comment` section. The main goal is that only ***registered users*** can post comments and only from ***their usernames***.

For now, I have a problem from who (*username*) the post is posting. On screenshot, you can see, that I can choose to post comment from user:**JOHUA**, but I'm currently logged in from user:**JOHN**[image]

I need to set permission for user to post comment only from his username (maybe I should remove `username` variable in **models.py**, **forms.py** and **admin.py** and to set it by default like user:***username***, or maybe you know how to remove other **usernames** from Username column, so register user can only choose his username.

I have been puzzling over this problem for a long time, so definitely need community help!

HERE IS SOME CODE:

`models.py`

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.username)
```

`forms.py`

```
from .models import Comment
from django import forms

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'body']
```

`admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Category, Comment

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


@admin.register(Comment)
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'body', 'post', 'created_on', 'active')
    list_filter = ('active', 'created_on')
    search_fields = ('username', 'email', 'body')
    actions = ['approve_comments']

    def approve_comments(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(active=True)

admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

Comment: You've shown your `ModelAdmin`, but the screenshot seems to be for a different view. Please show the code for that.

Comment: @C O D E simply add filter - [request.user] on data that you using in drop down menu for selecting users

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Can you please show me where and what exactly should I add, cause I've tried to play around with ```request.user``` method, and it didn't work for me, maybe I put it in incorrect place

Comment: @CODE in view where you render html create filter something like this: `users = User.object.filter(username=request.user)` then pass users into html `select`

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Ok, will try :)